# Android Subtle Memory leak analysis using MAT

Tags: java, android, multithreading, memory-leaks

I'm sorry if this can be a potential duplicate but I could not find any apropriate answer for my problem. So if you can reference a good source, I'll be more than happy to look at.

Here is the problem, I've been observing subtle memory leak while running my app. So after running for 16 hours, the heap dump is run through Eclipse Memory Analyzer and it suggests that the memory leak suspect is a lot of Thread not being garbage collected. The heap increases 3MB after running roughly 16 hours.

Here is the code that I used to run the back ground task:

```
private WorkerThread mWorkerThread;

private static Runnable mUploadTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Object[] data = dataQueue.poll();
            if( data != null ) {
                    uploadPacketviaAMQP((String)data[0], (String)data[1]);
        }
    };

    private static class WorkerThread extends HandlerThread{

    private Handler mWorkerHandler;

    public WorkerThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void postTask(Runnable task){
        mWorkerHandler.post(task);
    }

    public void prepareHandler(){
        mWorkerHandler = new Handler(getLooper());
    }
}
```

So here is the MAT screen grabs - LEFT panel is after running the app for 5 minutes, and RIGHT panel is after 16 hours. It does not make any sense to me because the reference is recursive, jumping to and fro and not leading to any concrete objects.

[image: MAT output]

How should I go about debug this problem?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary). It is really accurate for detecting memory leaks. It shows a leak trace in Logcat and also it attaches additional activity to the application which keeps a history of recent leaks. It should help to find possible place of memory leak in a code without digging in a dump heap.